# Only Show Full X-Axis Intervals VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, charts, intervals

I'm using the .NET charting library to show a line graph (voltage versus time). The full data length always varies (can be between 10ms of data up to ~250ms of data).

The issue I'm running into is that the final interval on the chart is usually cut short. For example if there is 230ms of data, and the chart has 50ms intervals, the final interval will be cut off after 30ms and won't show the complete interval on the x-axis. Ideally I want it to go all the way to 250ms and simply stop showing the data after 230ms (but extend the x-axis range to fully complete the interval).

Is there an option somewhere to not cut intervals short if the data ends? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the min and max explicitly

```vb
' make a test series, add points
Dim s As New Series()
For i = 0 To 230
    s.Points.Add(New DataPoint(i, i))
Next
' add series to chart
Chart1.Series.Add(s)
' set axis interval, min, and max
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 50
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 250
```

If you don't want to hard-code it, it can be done programatically

```vb
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(maxValue / interval) * interval
```

If you don't want to set the interval, you can calculate it based on the max value. This is an example but you may want to tweak the ranges and values

```vb
Private Function getInterval(maxValue As Double) As Double
    Select Case maxValue
        Case 0 To 10
            Return 1
        Case 10 To 50
            Return 5
        Case 50 To 100
            Return 10
        Case 100 To 1000
            Return 50
        Case Else
            Return 100
    End Select
End Function

''' 

Dim maxValue = 33
' make a test series, add points
Dim s As New Series()
For i = 1 To maxValue
    s.Points.Add(New DataPoint(i, i))
Next
' add series to chart
Chart1.Series.Add(s)
Dim interval = getInterval(maxValue)
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(maxValue / interval) * interval
```

Comment: The only issue is I have the X-Axis auto scaling, since if I only have 10ms worth of data I don't want the max to be set at 250ms (and because I don't calculate the interval I can't really set it programmatically). Is there any way to determine what the auto-scaled interval is?

Comment: You have the data. How difficult is it to determine the min and max of the current data set and then round that to the next ten or fifty?

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing as @teylyn but I wonder if it's ok for 10ms to be displayed on an axis with max 50ms. If so, keep the interval = 50 and just find the max of the data set and use my automatic code above. I can't see how to obtain the auto-scale interval from the axis.

Comment: @teylyn the issue is that the auto calculated interval can vary, therefore it will be hard to know what the auto calculated interval is in order to calculate the max.

Comment: @djv I suppose it wouldn't be too bad showing 10ms worth of data on a 50ms interval. This may be the route I have to go.

Comment: It doesn't have to be auto-calculated. YOU can calculate it. You can get the min and the max, you can set an algorithm that determines the interval. You can define the rules, why not do it? It just requires a few decisions and some simple maths.

Comment: Thanks @djv I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it this way and that there was some sort of backwards way of forcing full intervals / retrieving the auto calculated interval but as it seems there isn't, this is the route I'll have to go.